# Factorizing polynomials over fields other than $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: options, polynomials, modular-arithmetic

I'd like to take a polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]$ of the form $ax^2+bx+c$ and factor it into irreducible polynomials.

For example:

Input...

```
x^2+4
```

Output...

```
(x+1)(x-1)
```

Note that this factorization only makes sense in $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]$

I am also interested in identifying cases which are already irreducible.

For example:

Input...

```
x^2+2
```

Output...

```
Polynomial is irreducible.
```

---

So, is there a way to limit Mathematica, especially functions like `Solve` to fields other than $\mathbb{C}$?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

All of the [polynomial functions](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/AlgebraicOperationsOnPolynomials.html), have an option `Modulus` which allows you to specify an integer field, like $\mathbb{Z}_5$. In particular, `Factor` works on your example polynomial

```
Factor[x^2+4, Modulus -> 5]
(* (1 + x) (4 + x) *)
```

Additionally, `IrreduciblePolynomialQ` works to determine irreducibility of $x^2+2
$, as follows

```
IrreduciblePolynomialQ[x^2 + 2, Modulus -> 5]
(* True *)
```

Comment: Damn, I saw the question and was like — "this is an easy one, I'll just spread this cream cheese on my bagel and answer it", only to see you beat me by 8 seconds when I loaded your answer. Next time, I'll reverse the order

Comment: @R.M you have to be quick. :)

Comment: @R.M the real challange is to add a second answer that is even better when the first one seems almost perfect :) A real artist can turn such a dead case to an epic win.

Comment: @IstvánZachar I don't think Leonid can pull that off for this one. Although, there is room to cover other fields beyond integers, like rationals.

Comment: Thanks, really helpful. (and so fast too!)

Comment: @Harold you're welcome. Sometimes this place is like a tank of hungry piranhas, especially among the top rated users. :)

Comment: A real challenge is to update a post over and over again, while the first almost perfect answer is already accepted and the question seems to be just out of interests of the most users.

Comment: @Artes that's just being a sore loser. :)

Comment: @rcollyer Yes, if reputation would be the only advantage of it, but there is also a personal benefit of gaining the knowledge !

Comment: @Artes I don't disagree one bit. Just trying to bring a little humor.

Comment: @rcollyer Sorry to bother you and maybe I should post a question but despite reading the documentation I don't understand the `Modulus` option. The result of `Factor[x^2+4, Modulus -> 5]` is 
` (1 + x) (4 + x) ` which doesn't match the input. Could you kindly explain it to me.

Comment: @JackLaVigne `Modulus` restricts the numbers to a finite field. If I remember my analysis/modern algebra correctly, this means that $m$ are replaced by $m \bmod p$, where $p$ is the `Modulus`. This restriction means that polynomials will factor differently $\bmod p$ than over the full real numbers. So, to "reconstitute" the original polynomial we need to `Expand` it over the same `Modulus`, e.g. `Expand[(1 + x) (4 + x), Modulus -> 5]` produces `x^2 + 4`.

Answer (score 10):

**Solve with Modulus**

We can use `Solve` with domain specification like i.e. `Integers`, or with e.g. integers modulo `5`, then instead of specifying the domain one uses `Modulus`  :

```
Solve[x^2 + 4 == 0, x, Modulus -> 5]
```

> ```
> {{x -> 1}, {x -> 4}}
> ```

```
Times @@ ( x - Last @@@ %)
Expand[ %, Modulus -> 5]
```

> ```
> (-4 + x) (-1 + x)
> 4 + x^2
> ```

For an integer $n$, $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is a finite ring, while  for $n$ being a prime number, then it is also a field.

**Factorization with Modulus or Extension**

By default Mathematica factorizes polynomials over the **rationals** not over the **complexes**, if we'd like to do it over other fields we have to use :

1. `Modulus`  for factorization over rings of integers modulo $n$
2. `Extension` for factorization over extended fields of rationals by algebraic numbers

   In general, we have to use both options separately: if `Modulus` is not `0`, then Extension should be `None`.

We can use `FactorList` to get a list of the factors of a polynomial, where the first element is a numerical factor, and the rest are factorizing polynomials with their exponents :

```
FactorList[x^2 + 4, Modulus -> 5]
```

> ```
> {{1, 1}, {1 + x, 1}, {4 + x, 1}}
> ```

and in order to test whether we get irreducible polynomials, we can do this :

```
IrreduciblePolynomialQ[#, Modulus -> 5] & /@ First /@ Rest @ FactorList[x^2 + 4, Modulus -> 5]
```

> ```
> {True, True}
> ```

`Extension` may have several elements,e.g. `Extension->{a1, a2, a3,...,an}`, then a factorized polynomial may be rewritten in terms of  any rational combinations of algebraic numbers `a1,a2,...,an`.

We choose the following polynomial, being a minimal one having a root `Sqrt[2] + Sqrt[3]`, to show how `Extension` works :

```
MinimalPolynomial[Sqrt[2] + Sqrt[3], x]
```

> ```
> 1 - 10 x^2 + x^4
> ```

Next, we find its roots :

```
Solve[1 - 10 x^2 + x^4 == 0, x]
```

[image]

The solutions are algebraic numbers and in order to factorize this polynomial we have to extend the field of rationals, but we do it gradually :
 first we factorize over the rationals, then we extend it only by rational multiples of `Sqrt[2]`, next only by rational multiples of `Sqrt[3]` and finally by all rationals combinations of `Sqrt[2]` and `Sqrt[3]` :

```
Factor[1 - 10 x^2 + x^4, Extension -> #] & /@ {None, Sqrt[2], Sqrt[3], {Sqrt[2], Sqrt[3]}} // Column
```

[image]

And we check the results :

```
(Expand[#] === 1 - 10 x^2 + x^4) & /@ Last @ %
```

> ```
> {True, True, True, True}
> ```

One can set e.g. `Extension -> I` as well, to produce in this case the same output as `GaussianIntegers -> True` :

```
Factor[x^2 + 4, Extension -> I]
```

> ```
> (-2 I + x) (2 I + x)
> ```

Comment: This additional detail is verily useful. I appreciate it.

Comment: I added extended discussion of factorization over various fields, I believe you'll find it even more helpful than before.

Comment: Tremendous. We've learned a lot today.