# Surprises simplifying simple polynomials

Tags: symbolic, polynomials, simplifying-expressions

I came across some somewhat surprising behavior of `Simplify` today, on something very simple. Let's take two cubic polynomials that we know [have the same value](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PowerSum.html):

```
bySum = Sum[k^2, {k, 1, n}]
```

> ```
> (1/6)*n*(1 + 3*n + 2*n^2)
> ```

```
byBernoulli = (BernoulliB[3, n + 1] - BernoulliB[3])/3
```

> ```
> (1/3)*((1 + n)/2 - (3/2)*(1 + n)^2 + (1 + n)^3)
> ```

Now, I haven't done anything to simplify these two polynomials, so it's no surprise that they look different. However, `Simplify` helps less than you might think:

```
{bySum, byBernoulli} // Simplify
```

> ```
> {(1/6)*n*(1 + n)*(1 + 2*n), (1/6)*n*(1 + 3*n + 2*n^2)}
> ```

Mathematica can still figure out that they're the same if you ask it, but the `Simplify`'d forms are different.

```
bySum == byBernoulli // Simplify
```

> ```
> True
> ```

I was somewhat surprised by this. `FullSimplify` works as I'd expect, but this isn't the sort of problem where I'd expect to need it.

For what it's worth, this is Mathematica 8.0.4 on Windows 7 (x64).

Comment: The answers to [my question here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4522/what-is-the-difference-between-a-few-simplification-techniques) might shed some light on this issue.

Comment: From the answers, I guess that the "surprising behaviour" can be explained like this: when you evaluate Simplify[exp1==exp2], MMA doesn't simplify both expressions independently and see if they match, but it simplifies the subtraction and sees if it's zero, and it's not the same thing

Comment: A lot of "surprises" I've found come from not thinking about the `TreeForm` and the `LeafCount`. See also sorting: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2729/ordering-problem/2730

Comment: Note that for simple expressions such as polynomials in one variable, comparing them with an ExpandAll is as effective as Simplify.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**We get different results because `Simplify`, working with a smaller range of accessible transformations than `FullSimplify` does, applied to structurally very different expressions at the begining,  reaches only the local minimum of the default `ComplexityFunction`, being roughly close to LeafCount, unlike in case of `FullSimplify` even though its underlying `ComplexityFunction` may be the same.**

Having defined :

```
bySum = Sum[k^2, {k, 1, n}];
byBernoulli = (BernoulliB[3, n + 1] - BernoulliB[3])/3;
```

we get :

```
bySum == byBernoulli // Simplify
```

> ```
> True
> ```

because

```
Simplify[byBernoulli - bySum]
```

> ```
> 0
> ```

even though `Simplify` yields different results here :

```
  {bySum, byBernoulli} // Simplify
```

[image]

This is because at the begining we have  very different forms of the expressions which  we can observe with help of `TreeForm` and `LeafCount` assessing the complexity :

```
LeafCount /@ { bySum, byBernoulli, byBernoulli - bySum }
```

> ```
> {13, 26, 40}
> ```

```
TreeForm /@ {bySum, byBernoulli}
```

[image]

A kind of expression not involving special functions where  `FullSimplify` simplifies it in a much better way than `Simplify` one can find [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4522/what-is-the-difference-between-a-few-simplification-techniques/4542#4542). 
Knowing that algorithms behind `FullSimplify` contain a much wider range of transformations than `Simplify` the latter finds at certain stage  only a local minimum (not sufficient in case of `byBernoulli // Simplify` to reach the global minimum) of the actual complexity function  and therefore the resulting expressions are slightly different :

```
LeafCount /@ {bySum // Simplify, byBernoulli // Simplify}
```

> ```
> {13, 15}
> ```

```
TreeForm /@ {bySum // Simplify, byBernoulli // Simplify}
```

[image]

unlike in case of `FullSimplify` :

```
{bySum , byBernoulli } // FullSimplify
```

[image]

We needn't use `FullSimplify` to get the same expressions,  a simpler solution of the problem would be this :

```
{bySum, byBernoulli} // Factor
```

[image]

which is the same as the result of `FullSimplify` for the both expressions as well as `Simplify` for `bySum`. It should be mentioned here, that `FullSimplify` when applied to  a factorizable polynomials tends to give that polynomial in the factorized form, i.e. `Factor[poly]` yields by default its factorized form if `poly` is factorizable in the field of rationals, however if we extend the rationals appropriately the results will be different, e.g. `Factor[1 - 10 x^2 + x^4, Extension -> {Sqrt[2], Sqrt[3]}]` (see [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4362/factorizing-polynomials-over-fields-other-than-mathbbc/4372#4372)). So this is rather a special case, a more genreal approach (also for polynomials not factorizable in the rationals)
would be :

```
{bySum, byBernoulli} // Collect[#, n] & // Simplify
```

[image]

The result is the same as in the case of `byBernoulli // Simplify`.

Comment: I'm curious... did you really mean to bold an entire paragraph or was it an accident? Seems a bit excessive ;)

Comment: @R.M Since the post had become a bit long I wanted to emphasize the essence. Sometimes I cannot express my thoughts more briefly.

Comment: Fair enough... I would've probably used the quote block to get a yellow background to draw attention, but I see that you're using it for outputs.

Comment: Also, hope you don't mind me poking at such stuff — [I do edit a  lot!](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users?tab=editors&filter=all) and tend to notice things ;)

Comment: I find your suggestions meaningful, and if you see some flaws, edit my posts please.

Answer (score 11):

`FullSimplify` is `Simplify` with additional transformation rules; some of these rules may be necessary to simplify a polynomial to a form where you can see the equality explicitly.

In case of polynomials, I usually use `Simplify@Expand` to group terms the same way; `Expand` brings the polynomial in an unambiguous standard form, at which point both results should be the same already. Applying `Simplify` afterwards is merely a matter of making it more readable.

```
polySimplify = Simplify[Expand[#]] &;

bySum = Sum[k^2, {k, 1, n}];
bySum // polySimplify

byBernoulli = (BernoulliB[3, n+1]-BernoulliB[3])/3;
byBernoulli // polySimplify
```

> ```
> 1/6 n (1+3 n+2 n^2)
> 1/6 n (1+3 n+2 n^2)
> ```

Comment: Canonicalising things like that is often a neat trick in Mathematica. I find concatenating Together and Apart sometimes yields non-obvious insights.