# How to Simplify equations over a Ring with Mathematica?

Tags: equation-solving, simplifying-expressions, modular-arithmetic

For example, when we work over a ring, the equation `x^3=0` does not imply `x^2=0` or `x=0`, but the vice versa is true. Can we use Mathematica to Simplify equations over a ring?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to solve an equation over integer rings $\mathbb{Z}_n$  you should specify them with `Modulus` e.g.

```
Column[Solve[x^3 == 0, x, Modulus -> #] & /@ Range[2, 9]]
```

[image]

**Edit**

Since there was no further example of any expression to simplify over a finite ring let's define e.g. a polynomial which cannot be factorized over rationals (as `Mathematica` does by default)

```
p[x_] := x^5 + 3 x^4 + 6 x^3 - 2 x^2 + 1
Factor[p[x]]
p /@ Range[5]
```

> ```
> 1 - 2 x^2 + 6 x^3 + 3 x^4 + x^5
> {9, 121, 631, 2145, 5701}
> ```

however over rings $\mathbb{Z}_n$ it is evaluated automatically with `Mod[ p[x], n]`, (it has  the `Listable` attribute), thus

```
Column[ Mod[p /@ Range[2, 10], #] & /@ Range[2, 10]]
```

> ```
>  {{{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}},
>   {{1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0}},
>   {{1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1}},
>   {{1, 1, 0, 1, 4, 1, 1, 0, 1}},
>   {{1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3}},
>   {{2, 1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1}},
>   {{1, 7, 1, 5, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1}},
>   {{4, 1, 3, 4, 1, 6, 4, 1, 0}},
>   {{1, 1, 5, 1, 9, 1, 1, 5, 1}} }
> ```

On the other hand you can use `PolynomialMod`  to "simplify" a polynomial over a  ring $\mathbb{Z}_n$, e.g.

```
Column[ PolynomialMod[ p[x], #] & /@ Range[2, 6] ]
```

> ```
> 1 + x^4 + x^5
> 1 + x^2 + x^5
> 1 + 2 x^2 + 2 x^3 + 3 x^4 + x^5
> 1 + 3 x^2 + x^3 + 3 x^4 + x^5
> 1 + 4 x^2 + 3 x^4 + x^5
> ```

So to get the table `Column[ Mod[p /@ Range[2, 10], #] & /@ Range[2, 10]]` as above, you can `Apply` as well `PolynomialMod` on a specific level of an adequate `Table`, e.g.

```
Column[ Apply[ PolynomialMod[ p[#2], #1] &, Table[{i, j}, {i, 2, 10}, {j, 2, 10}], {2}] ] === 
Column[ Mod[ p /@ Range[2, 10], #] & /@ Range[2, 10]]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

In case you'd like to factorize `p[x]` over a finite field (for n prime $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is a field)  it can be done with `Modulus` as well, e.g.

```
Column[ Factor[ p[x], Modulus -> #] & /@ Prime @ Range[4]]
```

[image]

Some related details (e.g. `Extension` to work with polynomials and algebraic functions over rings of `Rationals` extended by selected algebraic numbers) you could find [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4362/factorizing-polynomials-over-fields-other-than-mathbbc/4372#4372).

Consider another polynomial

```
w[x_] := 6 - 12 x + x^2 - 2 x^3 - x^4 + 2 x^5
```

you can solve the equation `w[x] == 0` over the field of `Rationals` as well (by default `Mathematica` solves over `Complexes`, and then you needn't specify the domain), e.g.

```
Column[ Solve[w[x] == 0, x, #] & /@ {Integers, Rationals, Reals, Complexes} ]
```

[image]

You could factorize  completely  this polynomial with `Extension` :

```
Factor[ w[x]]
Factor[ w[x], Extension -> {Sqrt[2], Sqrt[3], I}]
```

[image]

There is also a package [AbstractAlgebra](https://sites.google.com/site/eaamhl/abstractalgebra/capabilities) to work with adequate algebraic concepts and a related book [Exploring Abstract Algebra with Mathematica](https://sites.google.com/site/eaamhl/eaam).

Comment: Nice. But it seems that the option `Modulus` is not capable to use with `Simplify` or `FullSimplify`. I don't want to solve the equations, but just want to simplify the relations of equations. Any idea?

Comment: @OsirisXu You can use `Simplify` first and then use  `Mod`. If your expression is quite simple as `x^3==0`you  needn't to use any simplifications e.g. `Mod[x^3, 9] /. x -> 6` yields `0` or directly evaluate `(Mod[x^3, 9] /. x -> 6) == 0`. Otherwise you should specify what you need giving an example.

Comment: Cool. Is there any way to work over Ring of rational numbers QQ? Thanks.

Comment: @OsirisXu If I understand what you mean, factorization is by default over `Rationals`, see more details http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4362/factorizing-polynomials-over-fields-other-than-mathbbc/4372#4372.  You can solve equations over `Rationals`, e.g. try `Solve[-(6/7) - 2 x + (3 x^2)/7 + x^3 == 0, x, Rationals]` and then `Solve[-(6/7) - 2 x + (3 x^2)/7 + x^3 == 0, x]`.

Comment: @OsirisXu I edited the answer to include more details which you'll find interesting. You could edit your question as well to make it more precise since e.g. "Is there any way to work over Ring of rational numbers ?" is slightly too general and there are many aspects which can be still unclear.