# Memory problem when solving a system of modular equations

Tags: equation-solving, modular-arithmetic

I need to solve the following system of modular equations, but the computation can't finish because I run out of memory (I have 12 GB of RAM). Is there any workaround to this problem? I am using *Mathematica* 11.0

System of equations:

```
Reduce[{Mod[6 a + 0 b + 1 c + 1 d + 0 e + 1 f + 0 g + 1 h + 0 i, 
    1235788] == 990685, 
  Mod[0 a + 3 b + 0 c + 0 d + 3 e + 0 f + 0 g + 0 h + 1 i, 1235788] ==
    404244, 
  Mod[4 a + 0 b + 0 c + 0 d + 0 e + 1 f + 1 g + 0 h + 0 i, 1235788] ==
    1228796, 
  Mod[1 a + 2 b + 1 c + 0 d + 1 e + 1 f + 1 g + 0 h + 0 i, 1235788] ==
    626461, 
  Mod[6 a + 0 b + 2 c + 0 d + 1 e + 1 f + 0 g + 0 h + 0 i, 1235788] ==
    814018, 
  Mod[4 a + 1 b + 1 c + 0 d + 1 e + 0 f + 0 g + 0 h + 1 i, 1235788] ==
    1052512, 
  Mod[1 a + 11 b + 0 c + 0 d + 0 e + 0 f + 0 g + 0 h + 0 i, 
    1235788] == 332360, 
  Mod[4 a + 2 b + 0 c + 2 d + 0 e + 0 f + 0 g + 0 h + 1 i, 1235788] ==
    417059, 
  Mod[7 a + 3 b + 1 c + 0 d + 0 e + 0 f + 1 g + 0 h + 0 i, 1235788] ==
    141258}, {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i}, Integers]
```

Comment: Proposed duplicates: [(4362)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4362/121),
[(7082)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7082/121)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `Modulus` option for `Reduce` to get the general solution.

```
{ToRules[Reduce[{
   6 a + 0 b + 1 c + 1 d + 0 e + 1 f + 0 g + 1 h + 0 i == 990685, 
   0 a + 3 b + 0 c + 0 d + 3 e + 0 f + 0 g + 0 h + 1 i == 404244, 
   4 a + 0 b + 0 c + 0 d + 0 e + 1 f + 1 g + 0 h + 0 i == 1228796, 
   1 a + 2 b + 1 c + 0 d + 1 e + 1 f + 1 g + 0 h + 0 i == 626461, 
   6 a + 0 b + 2 c + 0 d + 1 e + 1 f + 0 g + 0 h + 0 i == 814018, 
   4 a + 1 b + 1 c + 0 d + 1 e + 0 f + 0 g + 0 h + 1 i == 1052512, 
   1 a + 11 b + 0 c + 0 d + 0 e + 0 f + 0 g + 0 h + 0 i == 332360, 
   4 a + 2 b + 0 c + 2 d + 0 e + 0 f + 0 g + 0 h + 1 i == 417059, 
   7 a + 3 b + 1 c + 0 d + 0 e + 0 f + 1 g + 0 h + 0 i == 141258},
{a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i}, Modulus -> 1235788]]}
```

The constant `C[1]` returned in the result may be set to any integer; however, there are only finitely many distinct solutions because of the modular arithmetic.

Comment: Good method (and an upvote). Small correction though: there are only finitely many distinct (equivalence classes of) solutions when you account for the modulus.

Comment: Thank you @DanielLichtblau for keeping me honest. I have corrected my response.

Comment: KennyColnago this question seems like a duplicate to me.  I added a couple of candidates in a comment below the question.  Please review them and let me know if you agree or disagree.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: I agree. All three questions are resolved quickly by the `Modulus` option.

Answer (score 7):

`FindInstance` easily finds one solution, and fails to find two, so there might not be more:

```
FindInstance[{Mod[6 a + 0 b + 1 c + 1 d + 0 e + 1 f + 0 g + 1 h + 0 i,
       1235788] == 990685, 
    Mod[0 a + 3 b + 0 c + 0 d + 3 e + 0 f + 0 g + 0 h + 1 i, 
      1235788] == 404244, 
    Mod[4 a + 0 b + 0 c + 0 d + 0 e + 1 f + 1 g + 0 h + 0 i, 
      1235788] == 1228796, 
    Mod[1 a + 2 b + 1 c + 0 d + 1 e + 1 f + 1 g + 0 h + 0 i, 
      1235788] == 626461, 
    Mod[6 a + 0 b + 2 c + 0 d + 1 e + 1 f + 0 g + 0 h + 0 i, 
      1235788] == 814018, 
    Mod[4 a + 1 b + 1 c + 0 d + 1 e + 0 f + 0 g + 0 h + 1 i, 
      1235788] == 1052512, 
    Mod[1 a + 11 b + 0 c + 0 d + 0 e + 0 f + 0 g + 0 h + 0 i, 
      1235788] == 332360, 
    Mod[4 a + 2 b + 0 c + 2 d + 0 e + 0 f + 0 g + 0 h + 1 i, 
      1235788] == 417059, 
    Mod[7 a + 3 b + 1 c + 0 d + 0 e + 0 f + 1 g + 0 h + 0 i, 
      1235788] == 141258}, {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i}, 
   Integers][[1]] // TableForm
```

[image]

Comment: Wou ok, i am new to Mathematica and didn't know this existed. Thank you  very much :)

Comment: Ok, didnt know about that either , thanks :)