# Can Mathematica reliably determine the equality of any two constructible numbers?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, expression-manipulation

A [constructible number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_number) is any number which can be expressed with only natural numbers and the operators $+$, $-$, $\times$, $/$, $\sqrt{}$ (*square* root only). Is Mathematica's `Simplify` or `FullSimplify` guaranteed to be able to detect equality between two such numbers regardless of the complexity of the expression? More specifically, if I have two expressions `a` and `b` which represent the same constructible number, is either of the following guaranteed to yield `True`?

```
FullSimplify[a - b] == 0
FullSimplify[a == b]
```

[An algorithm for determining equality exists](https://mathoverflow.net/q/211538/56581), but from the documentation it's not clear, whether Mathematica will always be able to determine equality or just "try really hard".

Bonus question if the answer is "yes": how about [algebraic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_number), i.e. allowing radicals of other orders than 2.

Comment: The best thing to do is `RootReduce[]`; if the two algebraic numbers are indeed equal, `RootReduce[]` should be able to see that their difference is zero. Alternatively (or equivalently, if you think about it), use `MinimalPolynomial[]`.

Comment: Have you seen [Constructible numbers](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/48216/constructible-numbers)?

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
PossibleZeroQ[a - b, Method -> "ExactAlgebraics"]
```

The [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PossibleZeroQ.html#161883608) says:

> For explicit algebraic numbers the answer is provably correct