# How to factor real polynomials over complex field

Tags: polynomials

I'd like to factor polynomials over the complex field. For example, how do I factor `x^2+1` over $\mathbb{C}$?

`Factor[x^2+1]` and `Factor[x^2+1, Modulus->Complexes]` didn't work.

Comment: `Factor`'s `Modulus` option is for integer modulus and finite fields.  You could use `GaussianIntegers -> True` or `Extension -> I` for the Gaussian integers a+bi where a,b are integers - [see here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4362/72682). But that's not $\mathbb{C}$. Factoring polynomials over $\mathbb{C}$ is just a matter of finding all the complex roots with `Solve`.

Comment: ^ i.e `Times @@ ((x - #) & /@ (x /. Solve[x^2 + 1 == 0, x]))` gives `(-I + x) (I + x)`

Comment: I'd like to add an example: `Factor[x^2 + 2, Extension -> {I, Sqrt[2]}]` produces `(Sqrt[2] - I x)* (Sqrt[2] + I x)`.

Comment: Also `Solve[x^2 + 1 == 0, x] /. {Rule -> Subtract, List -> Times}`
and `Roots[x^2 + 1 == 0, x] /. {Equal -> Subtract, Or -> Times}`. It's surprising to me WRI hasn't written a function to factor over the `Reals` and `Complexes`, considering the other sugary shortcuts they've provided. -- Thirdly, `Product[x - Root[Function[x, #], k], {k, Exponent[#, x]}] &[x^2 + 1]`.

Comment: What does `Extension -> I` do?

Comment: @cheeseboardqueen read this about [field extensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_extension) . Suppose you use `Extension->Sqrt[2]` then it factors over the field consisting of elements $a+b\sqrt2$ for integers $a,b$. For `Extension->I` that means we factorize over the [Gaussian Integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integer) which you can also enable with `GaussianIntegers->True`.

Comment: @flinty, I see thank you. It is strange that there is no simpler way of doing this yet.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Factoring polynomials to factors involving complex coefficients](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8255/factoring-polynomials-to-factors-involving-complex-coefficients)

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically right, but sometimes *sloooow*:

```
factorComplete[poly_] := With[{var = Variables[poly]},
   Factor[
     poly,
     Extension -> ToNumberField[
        SolveValues[poly == 0, First@var],
        All][[1, 1]] (* extract generator *)
     ] /; 
    Length@var == 1 && PolynomialQ[poly, x]
   ];
factorComplete[x^2 + 1]

(*  (-I + x) (I + x)  *)
```

Faster:

```
factorComplete2[poly_] := With[{var = Variables[poly]},
   Module[{factors, coeff},
     factors = Solve[poly == 0, First@var];
     coeff = Coefficient[poly, First[var]^Length[factors]];
     coeff (Times @@ Flatten[factors /. Rule -> Subtract])
     ] /; Length@var == 1 && PolynomialQ[poly, x]
   ];
factorComplete2[x^5 + x + 1] // ToRadicals
```

$$\eqalign{
\left(x+\sqrt[3]{-1}\right) & \left(x-(-1)^{2/3}\right) \cr
  & \left(x-\frac{1-i \sqrt{3}}{3\ 2^{2/3} \sqrt[3]{25-3
   \sqrt{69}}}-\frac{1}{6} \left(1+i \sqrt{3}\right)
   \sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{2} \left(25-3
   \sqrt{69}\right)}-\frac{1}{3}\right) \cr
  & \left(x-\frac{1+i
   \sqrt{3}}{3\ 2^{2/3} \sqrt[3]{25-3
   \sqrt{69}}}-\frac{1}{6} \left(1-i \sqrt{3}\right)
   \sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{2} \left(25-3
   \sqrt{69}\right)}-\frac{1}{3}\right) \cr
  & \left(x+\frac{1}{3} \left(-1+\sqrt[3]{\frac{2}{25-3
   \sqrt{69}}}+\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{2} \left(25-3
   \sqrt{69}\right)}\right)\right) \cr}$$

Answer (score 0):

I just tried `Factor[x^2 + 1, Extension -> Sqrt[-1]]` and it worked!!

Edit: See comments below. It didn't work over $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Try it on other real polynomials.

Comment: I this what it's doing there is that it's factoring over $\mathbb{Q}[i]$ and not $\mathbb{C}$ unfortunately because `Factor[x^2 + 3, Extension -> Sqrt[-1]]` did not factor.  *sigh*

Comment: This won't work: `Factor[x^3 + 1, Extension -> Sqrt[-1]]` you'll get two factors $(1 + x)$ and $(1 - x + x^2)$ which is irreducible in the Gaussian integers (your field extension). Instead you should use `Solve` to find all the roots a,b,c,d.... and then express the factors as (x-a)(x-b)(x-c)(x-d).... etc to fully factor in $\mathbb{C}$. This has already been shown in the comments.

Comment: @flinty Is that what `{Rule -> Subtract, List -> Times}` and `{Equal -> Subtract, Or -> Times}` is doing then? To be more specific that "subtract" creates the difference, "list" lists the factors, and "times" is the function (multiplication)?

Comment: @cheeseboardqueen those are rules used in a replacement `/.`. It converts `Solve`'s solutions of the form `List[List[Rule[x,a],List[Rule[x,b]],...]` into a product (x-a)(x-b)... or more fully `Times[Subtract[x,a],Subtract[x,b],...]` so yes that's answer finds the roots with `Solve` and then builds an expression of the fully $\mathbb{C}$-factored polynomial.

Comment: Thank you @flinty! + others!